# rendering dynamic image URLs

Tags: vuejs3

I have a URL that has a dynamic URL. It prints correctly in the console, the URL is correct but will not render.

```
    </div>
        <div data-v-145c="" class="w-1/3"><img data-v-145c="" src='https://storage.googleapis.com/casestudy2108.appspot.com/{{image}}.svg' alt="The java Course" class="w-16 h-16 mx-auto"></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

in template

```
const props = defineProps(
    ['course']
);

const store = useStore();

let image = props?.course?.topic

console.log("image " + image) <--- prints what is expected.
```

I also tried `:src` with no avail but perhaps I used it wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template interpolation (a.k.a *"mustache"*) doesn't work in attributes.

Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
:src="`https://storage.googleapis.com/casestudy2108.appspot.com/${image}.svg`"
```